# Error while running python from atom editor. While its running using idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I just start with python. When I try to run python using Atom it gives me `'python' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error message. 
I just install **python3.6.1**.
run from a command line it gives-

```
C:\Users\Priya Jain>python
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Set Environment Variable to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\
```

**then my question is why from atom editor it is not running using script package**.

Comment: Check out: https://discuss.atom.io/t/cannot-get-python-to-run-from-atom-on-windows/15585/15

Comment: follow the same process but still not working

Answer (score 0):

I just solved your problem in my laptop: you have to re-install python and choose from the installing menu "Add python to environment variables".
This should work.